# Java and XML (JAXP) - What about caching and thread-safety?

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, caching, jaxp

1. I'd like to know which **objects can be reused** (in the same or different document) when using the *Java API for XML* processing, JAXP:

   - `DocumentBuilderFactory`
   - `DocumentBuilder`
   - `XPath`
   - `Node`
   - <strike>`ErrorHandler`</strike> (EDIT: I forgot that this has to be implemented in my own code, sorry)
2. Is it recommended to **cache** those objects or do the JAXP implementations already cache them?
3. Is the **(re)use** of those objects **thread-safe**?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Reuse**

In the same thread those objects can and should be reused.  For example you can use the DocumentBuilder to parse multiple documents.

**Thread Safety**

DocumentBuilderFactory used to explicity state it was not thread safe, I believe this is still true:

> An implementation of the
>   DocumentBuilderFactory class is NOT
>   guaranteed to be thread safe. It is up
>   to the user application to make sure
>   about the use of the
>   DocumentBuilderFactory from more than
>   one thread.

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html

From Stack Overflow, DocumentBuilder does not appear to be thread safe either.  However in Java SE 5 a reset method was added to allow you to reuse DocumentBuilders:

- [Is DocumentBuilder.parse() thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737/is-documentbuilder-parse-thread-safe)
- http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#reset()
- http://www.junlu.com/msg/289939.html (about DocumentBuilder.reset())

XPath is not thread safe, from the Javadoc

> An XPath object is not thread-safe and
>   not reentrant. In other words, it is
>   the application's responsibility to
>   make sure that one XPath object is not
>   used from more than one thread at any
>   given time, and while the evaluate
>   method is invoked, applications may
>   not recursively call the evaluate
>   method.

- http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html

Node is not thread safe, from Xerces website

> Is Xerces DOM implementation
>   thread-safe?   No. DOM does not
>   require implementations to be thread
>   safe. If you need to access the DOM
>   from multiple threads, you are
>   required to add the appropriate locks
>   to your application code.

- http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html#faq-1

ErrorHandler is an interface, so it is up to your implementation of that interface to ensure thread-safety.  For pointers on thread-safety you could start here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: This is from the Xerces web site http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html#faq-1